# Make one word of a sentence in UIButton bolded/underlined (Swift)

Tags: swift, string, xcode, uibutton, nsattributedstring

I am just looking to bold (or underline) a single word of a text sentence in UIButton programatically in Swift. I can't find the information to do this anywhere

Comment: You seem to have found out about NSAttributedString, so what’s the problem?

Comment: You can use setAttributedTitle method to ad an attributed string to your button title.

Answer (score 1):

In this example I set the title of a UIButton to “Pay tribute” with the word “tribute” underlined (along with various other decorations):

```
    let mas = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Pay Tribute", attributes: [
        .font: UIFont(name:"GillSans-Bold", size:16)!,
        .foregroundColor: UIColor.purple,
    ])
    mas.addAttributes([
        .strokeColor: UIColor.red,
        .strokeWidth: -2,
        .underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
    ], range: NSMakeRange(4, mas.length-4))
    self.button.setAttributedTitle(mas, for:.normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use these helpers to create attributed strings:

```
extension NSAttributedString {
    typealias Style = [Key: Any]
}

extension Array where Element == NSAttributedString {
    func joined() -> NSAttributedString {
        let mutable = NSMutableAttributedString()
        for element in self {
            mutable.append(element)
        }
        return mutable.copy() as! NSAttributedString
    }
}

extension String {
    func styled(_ style: NSAttributedString.Style = [:]) -> NSAttributedString {
        return NSAttributedString(string: self, attributes: style)
    }
}
```

Here's how to use them to create a button with a partially underlined title:

```
let rootView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
rootView.backgroundColor = .white

let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
let title = [
    "Hello, ".styled(),
    "world!".styled([.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
    ].joined()
button.setAttributedTitle(title, for: .normal)
button.sizeToFit()
button.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 50)
rootView.addSubview(button)

import PlaygroundSupport
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = rootView
```

Result:

[image: partially underlined button]